# Conditional Prolog Sorting approach

Tags: programming-languages, prolog

I am new to prolog language. I came across an interesting problem in prolog.

Generally, quicksort works well for large lists. But for smaller lists, insertion sort works better than quicksort. How can i write a sorting algorithm in Prolog that uses quicksort
initially, but switches to insertion sort for sublists of 15 or fewer elements.

The hint is that we can count the number of elements during the partition operation. But i don't know how to form an algorithm for this problem. Can anyone please guide/help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For more efficient ways, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429479/sorting-a-list-in-prolog/8430692#8430692

Answer (score 1):

You can make several clauses for the `mysort` rule that choose the algorithm based on the length of the list, like this:

```
mySort(In, Out) :-
    count(In, Cnt),
    Cnt < 15,
    insertionSort(In, Out).
mySort(In, Out) :-
    count(In, Cnt),
    Cnt >= 15,
    quickSort(In, Out).

quickSort(In, Out) :-
    partition(In, Left, Right),
    mySort(Left, SortedLeft),
    mySort(Right, SortedRight),
    mergeSorted(SortedLeft, SortedRight, Out).
```

The trick is that the `quickSort/2` rule references `sort`, not `quickSort`, after partitioning the input. This means that as soon as the count drops below 15, `insertionSort` is going to be used to sort the smaller partitions.

Comment: Is `count/2` defined somewhere, or do you mean `length/2`?

Comment: @mbratch This is intended as a skeletal implementation, so `partition`, `mergeSorted`, and `count` are up to the OP to define (or to use an existing one, such as `length/2` for `count/2`).

Comment: the OP wanted `partition` also to count the length, to spare the unneeded extra traversal.

Comment: @WillNess This is only a skeleton of the algorithm - the OP is free to optimize this, passing around the counts. The key idea is in these three clauses.

Comment: sort/2 is a built-in predicate. You should not be able to redefine it. What Prolog did you use? It must be a very old version.

Comment: @false Thanks, I renamed this predicate to be consistent with the rest of the answer, where I am not using "real" names. The idea was to demonstrate the basic approach without writing any real code. I haven't been actively using Prolog since mid-nineties, so I had no idea it's not possible to redefine a built-in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`partition` puts each element either to one or the other sublist. so just maintain two more arguments which are counts for the sublists, starting as 0, and increment the corresponding counter when adding another element to its sublist:

```
part([]    ,[],[],0 ,0).
part([P|LS],L , R,CL,CR):- part(P,LS,L,[],R,[],0,CL,0,CR).

part(_,[]    ,LZ,LZ,RZ,RZ,CL,CL,CR,CR).
part(P,[X|LS],L ,LZ,R ,RZ,IL,CL,JR,CR):-
   X < P -> L=[X|T],I2 is IL+1, part(P,LS,T,LZ,R,RZ,I2,CL,JR,CR)
 ; .....
```