# Sort predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to figure out how sort/2 is implemented in Prolog. I would like to see how it works but I cannot find the code for it anywhere. Does somebody know how it is implemented?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429479/sorting-a-list-in-prolog)

Comment: What I would like to do is sort by the second element in decending order without removing dublicates. I have at the moment done it like "sort4(List, Sorted) :- sort(2, @>=, List, Sorted)." however i am not allowed to use anything else then sort/2 so I am thought I could change the original function and implement that as a helper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just are seaching for any sorting algorithm you can always use bubblesort **cough**. It is one of the most simple and inefficient ways to sort a list, but - depending on the implementation - will run through an already sorted list in linear time. Bubblesort does not remove duplicates. This implementation does descending order:

```
bubblesort(List, SortedList) :-
    bubbleit(List, List1), 
    ! ,
    bubblesort(List1, SortedList) .
bubblesort(List, List).

bubbleit([X,Y|Rest], [Y,X|Rest]) :-
    X < Y, 
    ! .
bubbleit([Z|Rest], [Z|Rest1]) :-
    bubbleit(Rest, Rest1).

?- bubblesort([1,2,5,4,7,3,2,4,1,5,3],L).
L = [7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1].
```

---

If you want to sort for the second element in a list `[_,E|]` change the the first `bubbleit` rule to

```
bubbleit([X,Y|Rest], [Y,X|Rest]) :-
    X = [_,XX|_],
    Y = [_,YY|_],
    XX < YY, 
    ! .

?- bubblesort([[a,3],[b,5],[c,1],[d,4]],L).
L = [[b, 5], [d, 4], [a, 3], [c, 1]].
```

Comment: Thank you! How would it work if you had a list of lists so [[ , ], [ , ]] and wanted to sort by the second element of each sublist?

Comment: @fewfrg i added a method to the answer

Comment: @fewfrg ^^ you can accept an answer by clicking the grey checkmark left to the answer below the upvote/donvote buttons

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog, [`sort/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) is a "built-in", so it's in C.

The file seems to be `src/pl-lists.c` of the distribution.

Here it is:

https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/master/src/pl-list.c

At line 543:

```
static
PRED_IMPL("sort", 2, sort, PL_FA_ISO)
{ PRED_LD

  return pl_nat_sort(A1, A2,
             TRUE, SORT_ASC,
             0, NULL, FALSE PASS_LD);
}
```

`pl_nat_sort` is in the same file

The comment is historically interesting:

> Natural merge sort. Code contributed by   Richard O'Keefe and integrated
> into SWI-Prolog by Jan Wielemaker. The  nice   point  about this code is
> that it uses no  extra  space  and   is  pretty  stable  in performance.
> Richards claim it that many  qsort()   implementations  in libc are very
> slow. This isn't the case for glibc   2.2, where this performs about the
> same  as  the  previous  qsort()    based  implementation.

Presumably Richard O'Keefe notes:

> I've been using a variant of this code  in a sorting utility since about
> 1988. It leaves the UNIX sort(1) program in   the dust. As you may know,
> sort(1) breaks the input into  blocks  that   fit  in  memory, sorts the
> blocks using qsort(), and writes the blocks out to disc, then merges the
> blocks. For files that fit into memory,   the  variant of this code runs
> about twice as fast as sort(1). Part of  that is better I/O, but part is
> just plain not using qsort().

Dayum. That brings back memories of writing sorting algorithms in '89.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching quicksort.

Here is one link: https://www.codepoc.io/blog/prolog/4934/prolog-program-to-sort-a-list-using-quick-sort

Here is another example:-

```
quicksort([], []).
quicksort([X | Tail], Sorted):-
    split(X, Tail, Small, Big),
    quicksort(Small, SortedSmall),
    quicksort(Big, SortedBig),
    concatenate(SortedSmall, [X| SortedBig], Sorted).

split(X, [], [], []).
split(X, [Y| Tail], [Y | Small], Big):-
    X > Y, !,
    split(X, Tail, Small, Big).
split(X, [Y| Tail], Small, [Y | Big]):-
    split(X, Tail, Small, Big).

concatenate([],List,List).
concatenate([Item|List1],List2,[Item|List3]) :-
    concatenate(List1,List2,List3).


?-quicksort([1,7,4,3,6,5,9,8,12,1],L).
L = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12]
false
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it? What I would like to do is sort by the second element in decending order without removing dublicates. I have at the moment done it like "sort4(List, Sorted) :- 
    sort(2,  @>=, List,  Sorted)." however i am not allowed to use anything else then sort/2 so I am thought I could change the original function and implement that as a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

The *merge sort* algorithm is a natural fit for Prolog. Not to mention trivial to implement in a language with recursion and lists as fundamental.

Here's a SWI Playground: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/swi-prolog-merge-sort.pl

```
merge_sort( [], [] ).             % The empty list is by definition ordered
merge_sort( [X], [X] ).           % So is a list of length one
merge_sort( Unsorted, Sorted ) :- % otherwise...
  partition( Unsorted, L, R ) ,   % partition the list into 2 halves
  merge_sort(L,L1),               % recursively sort the left half
  merge_sort(R,R1),               % recursively sort the right half
  merge(L1,R1,Sorted)             % merge the newly-sorted halves
    .                             % See? simple!

partition( []      , []     , []     ).   % the empty list gets partitioned into two empty lists
partition( [X]     , [X]    , []     ).   % a left of length 1 gets partitioned into itself and an empty list
partition( [X,Y|L] , [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % list of length 2 or more gets popped and divided between left and right halves
  partition(L,Xs,Ys)                      % with the remainder being recursively partitioned.
    .                                     % Easy!

merge( []     , []     , []     ).        % merging to empty lists is trivial
merge( []     , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Ys] ).        % merging an empty list and a non-empty list is easy
merge( [X|Xs] , []     , [X|Xs] ).        % merging a non-empty list and an empty list is easy
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [Lo,Hi|Zs] ) :-  % otherwise...
  compare(X,Y,Lo,Hi),                     % compare the two terms, put them in collating sequence
  merge(Xs,Ys,Zs)                         % and recursively merge the tails
  .                                       % Easy!

compare( X , Y , X, Y ) :- X @=< Y. % if X <= Y, X is Lo, and Y is Hi
compare( X , Y , Y, X ) :- X @>  Y. % if X >  Y, Y is Lo, and X is Hi
```